# Image rotation by very small step size in openCV c++

Tags: c++, image, opencv, rotation, transformation

I'm trying to rotate an image by small degrees like 1 degree or below 1 degree,

Consider this is my **Source Image** and I'm trying to rotate it by 1 degree in **MATLAB** and **OpenCV (C++)** :

```
0   0   0  0
0  255 255 0
0  255 255 0
0   0   0  0
```

When I rotate it in **MATLAB** by 1 degree this is the result:

```
0                   0                  2.223835069639144   0
2.223835069639553   252.7942370468069  2.527942370468065   0
0                   252.7942370468065  252.794237046807    2.223835069639648
0                   2.223835069639184  0                   0
```

This is the code in **MATLAB**:

```
sourceImage = [0 0 0 0; 0 255.0 255.0 0; 0 255.0 255.0 0; 0 0 0 0];
rotationDegree = 1.0;

shearInX_Y1 = (cosd(rotationDegree)-1)/sind(rotationDegree);
shearInX_Y2 = sind(rotationDegree);

transformationMatrix = [(1 + shearInX_Y1*shearInX_Y2), (2*shearInX_Y1 + ...
    ((shearInX_Y1)^2)*shearInX_Y2), 0; (shearInX_Y2), (1 + shearInX_Y1*shearInX_Y2), 0; 0, 0, 1];

tform = affine2d(transformationMatrix);
imref = imref2d(size(sourceImage));
imref.XWorldLimits = imref.XWorldLimits-mean(imref.XWorldLimits);
imref.YWorldLimits = imref.YWorldLimits-mean(imref.YWorldLimits);
transformedImg2 = imwarp(sourceImage , imref, tform, 'OutputView', imref, 'Interp', 'bilinear');

transformedImg2
```

The transformationMatrix in Matlab (which is our rotation matrix) is:

```
transformationMatrix =

 9.998476951563913e-01    -1.745240643728003e-02                         0
 1.745240643728351e-02     9.998476951563913e-01                         0
                     0                         0     1.000000000000000e+00
```

And the content of "tform.T" is:

```
9.998476951563913e-01    -1.745240643728003e-02      0
1.745240643728351e-02     9.998476951563913e-01      0
0                         0                          1
```

And the content of "rotationMatrix" in OpenCV is:

```
9.998476951563913e-01    1.745240643728351e-02      -0.008650050796837391
-1.745240643728351e-02     9.998476951563913e-01     0.008802355640446121
```

But when I do the rotation by 1 degree in **OpenCV (C++)** This is the result:
(which is same as source image!) which means openCV has a problem with small rotations!

```
0   0   0  0
0  255 255 0
0  255 255 0
0   0   0  0
```

This is the code I use for rotation in OpenCV (C++): (Rotation is done with respect to image center)

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

# define INTERPOLATION_METHOD INTER_CUBIC
// INTER_AREA
// INTER_LINEAR
// INTER_NEAREST

Mat rotateImage(Mat sourceImage, double rotationDegree);    

int main(){

     Mat sourceImage = Mat::zeros(4, 4, CV_64F);
     sourceImage.at<double>(1, 1) = 255.0;
     sourceImage.at<double>(1, 2) = 255.0;
     sourceImage.at<double>(2, 1) = 255.0;
     sourceImage.at<double>(2, 2) = 255.0;

    double rotationDegree = 1.0;
    Mat rotatedImage = rotateImage(sourceImage, rotationDegree);    

    cout << "sourceImage: \n" << sourceImage << endl << endl;
    cout << "rotatedImage : \n" << rotatedImage << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}

Mat rotateImage(Mat sourceImage, double rotationDegree){

    double rowOfImgCenter;
    double colOfImgCenter;
    rowOfImgCenter = sourceImage.rows / 2.0 - 0.5;
    colOfImgCenter = sourceImage.cols / 2.0 - 0.5;
    Point2d imageCenter(colOfImgCenter, rowOfImgCenter);

    Mat rotationMatrix;
    rotationMatrix = getRotationMatrix2D(imageCenter, rotationDegree, 1.0);

    Mat rotatedImage;
    warpAffine(sourceImage, rotatedImage, rotationMatrix, sourceImage.size(), INTERPOLATION_METHOD);

    return rotatedImage;
}
```

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: I cannot replicate getting back the same source image with OpenCV.  Can you edit your posted code to be a complete example?  The Matlab code might be helpful as well.

Comment: @RobertPrévost: I've updated my question with codes in matlab and c++, I hope now it is more clear.

Comment: Did you try different interpolation methods? Can you post your matlab rotation matrix?

Comment: @Micka: I update the code by defining INTERPOLATION_METHOD, I've tried with all interpolation methods (INTER_CUBIC, INTER_LINEAR, INTER_AREA, INTER_NEAREST) but still gives me the same source image after rotation by 1 degree! I'm looking for openCV configuration to find a way for increasing the accuracy (may be this could solve the problem). 
Matlab rotation matrix is exactly "transformationMatrix" inside the matlab code.

Comment: can you please post the transformation matrix elements of matlab (content of `tform`) and opencv (`rotationMatrix`)?

Comment: @Micka: I update the post by adding those matrices.

Comment: why is the last column of the matlab transformation matrix [0,0,1]? Does this mean it will rotate around the matrix origin instead of its center? How does the fact influence the result, that matlab uses 1-indexed matrices but openCV uses 0-indexed matrices? I find it hard to compare... Did you try to transform and interpolate the pixels manually?

Comment: @Micka: [0, 0, 1] in transformation matrix is just because of definition (and using homogeneous coordinates) and it will rotate around center of the matrix. It doesn't make any difference to be 0-indexed or 1-indexed matrices, because both of them mean the origin (not the center) of the matrix. I used "imageJ" software to compare my results, and the result of Matlab is quite similar to this software, but the result of openCV is wrong!

Comment: no, a transformation matrix [cos, sin, 0; -sin, cos, 0; 0,0,1] will rotate around the image origin (not the center)! Just compare the transformation matrices of opencv and matlab you provided, they differ in the last column! Rotation around image center means: 1. translate around half the image size; 2. rotate around image origin; 3. translate back for half the image size. Not sure whether this is the reason for the differing results, but it's definitely that way (believe me, I've studied computer graphics at university). Maybe there is inaccuracy in openCV but make sure same assumptions.

Comment: can you compare to matlab's `imrotate` function? https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imrotate.html which will rotate around the image center? And post the results.

Comment: maybe have a look at the accepted answer here, too: https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/215259-why-is-imrotate-not-rotating-an-image-about-its-center-point where someone explains it a little further.

Comment: @Micka: Of course it will rotate around image origin, and that's why I have  these lines of codes: imref.XWorldLimits = imref.XWorldLimits-mean(imref.XWorldLimits); ... (in matlab) and rowOfImgCenter = sourceImage.rows / 2.0 - 0.5; ... (in openCV), openCV code works for higher than 2 degrees of rotation and it's problem is with degree 1 or below ... My main problem is that the rotation in openCV doesn't work with small changes, the result of 45 degree rotation is same as result of 45.1 degree rotation which should not! Btw, thank you.

Comment: sorry, my matlab knowledge isn't that great. Can you add the values of imref.XWorldLimits and mean(imref.XWorldLimits)? Can you use linear interpolation in matlab to make the results better comparable?

Comment: @Micka: No problem. imref.XWorldLimits = [0.5 4.5], mean(imref.XWorldLimits) = 2.5, and same for YWorldLimits ... , I'm using bilinear interpolation too in matlab (look to matlab code). It would be great if the result of 45 degree rotation could not be same as 46 degree in openCV using bilinear interpolation!

Comment: Ok, I recompiled openCV with `INTER_BITS = 8` (5 was default) and get different results (but still different from matlab results): Rotating 1 degree: `[0,0, 1.93771..., 0; 1.93771..., 253.007..., ...]` and changes for every one or two 0.1 steps... I'll test different INTER_BITS values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128085/discussion-between-bugreader-and-micka).